# AtomikosSQLException: Transaction is marked for rollback only or has timed out

Tags: java, transactional, atomikos

I'm using Atomicko for transaction and Tomcat version 8.5 as a Application server.
While executing the select query in Ibatis am getting AtomikosSQLException. Below is my exception 
Cause: com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: Transaction is marked for rollback only or has timed out. How to resolve this issue either jta.property file or code level?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue using Atomiko 4 jars and increase the max time out in jta properies. Thank You